# How to make a subdomain resolve the root domain

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, domain, subdomain

I have a domain,

`example.com`

that belongs to an Apache server. I want visitors to both

`us.example.com`

and

`cn.example.com`

to see what is seen when visiting example.com. The subdomain must remain in the browser address bar. Also, I do not control the IP address of the site.

Comment: What's wrong with this question?

Comment: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en

Comment: I spent half an hour looking for this exact question on ServerFault before asking it myself.

Comment: So what don't you understand about redirecting and the fact you will loose your rank if you don't ?

Comment: When I set this up as an A record, I got a bad_http_conf error. When I set it up with a CNAME record, it didn't resolve. Rather than assume I was going about it correctly, I asked a question here that allowed for solutions that didn't involve the methods I had already pursued. The response here seems to indicate other users think I'm just being lazy. The problem is a lack of technical vocabulary to describe my problem. In this case, the magic word was "mirror". As soon as I discovered that, I was on my way to a solution.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are speaking about. Did you *actually* read the content of my link ?

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you're referring to with your link. I don't intend for visitors to different domains to always see the same content. I merely need it to be that way so I have actual live subdomains for testing. Ultimately, us.example.com and cn.example.com will go to different places.

Comment: Ok, that wasn't clear in the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, @Iain for getting me on the right track. It turns out what I need is a [mirror](http://www.apache.org/info/mirror-proxy.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documentation for the (unspecified) server software that you're using. For example if using apache httpd and vhosts you could get this to work with a `ServerAlias` directive.

Other server software will have it's own way of doing the same thing.